# ignite is slower than mariadb when use same data and select statement?

Tags: mariadb, ignite

I make a simple test use ignite and mariadb,
same data in ignite and mariadb about 100000 line,
and then use same select statement to load data, find ignite is slower than mariadb lots of sql.
that's why? i think ignite is more faster than relation db.

Comment: We'd need more information to be able to get to the bottom of this. I'd suggest starting with this documentation, which explains why they might not be directly comparable: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/sql-tuning#basic-considerations-gridgain-vs-rdbms

Comment: Show us the code for each.  Hopefully, it is no more than 10 lines each.

Comment: Is the Ignite data sharded?  Is parallelism being used?  More details, please.

Comment: It's in same machine，just use a machine(4core and 12g memeory), both ignite and mysql use the initial configuration，and not  any optimization,.

Comment: I know the compare is unfair, but i can't find offical compare by google, I just want to know which case can use ignite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have seem the article, [enter link description here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/sql-tuning#basic-considerations-gridgain-vs-rdbms).
learn a more ignite and rmdb, i think ignite is great well in large data.